# Using Fold[ or Map[ Better?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I'm working through MMA Cookbook by Mangano, page 54. He shows `Map` is a compact form of `Fold` function. Is using `Fold` function important?

```
myMap3[f_, l_] := Fold[Prepend[#1, f[#2]]&, {}, l]
myMap3[Sqrt, {1, 2, 3}]
(* Out: {Sqrt[3], Sqrt[2], 1} *)
```

I value writing better MMA code. Mastering Functional forms, then moving into Rewrite-rules. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure. `Fold` solves problems that `Map` does not (at least not without uncomfortable contortions). `Map` is perhaps more intuitive to me and certainly very convenient. It also has a nice infix form (`/@`), which is handy. You would certainly want to be aware of both to write idiomatic MMA code.

Comment: As @MarcoB notes, `Fold` can solve problems that `Map` cannot. I have not read Mangano's book, but to me, the more interesting comparison is between `Fold` and recursive functions. Understanding why recursion is more powerful than `Fold` is valuable exercise.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it. @Shredderroy

Comment: Magnano's point was, "so you can understand" what is happening inside of the Map[ command, by a drawn out equivalent. I'm really enjoying trying to get inside MMA head. Just everything is so abstract & full of symbols.